# VPN server for some sites

Tags: server, proxy, devops, vpn

how can build a VPN server for using some sites?

for example, I want to build a VPN server for just viewing example.com and asite.com, and when anyone wants to see other sites requests will be failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem with IP restriction
You can easily run this with Mikrotik